# Xcode server pre-integration script trigger exited with non-zero status 127

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcode-server

I have an Xcode project that builds perfectly fine on my client computer and server computer. I am trying to build it via xcode server and since I am using cocoapods for some dependencies my understanding is that I need a pre-integration script that will install the pods.

So what I have is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd <local path to project on server>

pod install
```

And when I run integrate the errors that come out are:

```
Trigger Error: Trigger exited with non-zero status 127.


Trigger Error: Exception trying to execute trigger: NSInternalInconsistencyException: Couldn't posix_spawn: error 2
```

There is a "fix now" button on the right side of the screen and clicking that takes me to my pre-integration script so I am assuming the error lies there.

The error messages themselves don't lead me to anything obvious.. Any suggestions for how to correctly accomplish this are appreciated!